# Update UIView inside a UIScrollView using Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm stuck on this problem since 2 days and I don't know how to proceed & I didn't find a solution on internet so I'm going to ask advices here.

My problem is about AutoLayout, UIScrollView and UIView : Please take a look on the schema I made to explain you what I want to do.

The blue box represent labels, the green box the UIScrollView and the Pink the UIView. The UIView contains a chart (using the great iOS-Charts library). The thing is, when the user scroll to the right, I add data to the chart and it becomes longer, no problem with that.

But as soon I add constraints, nothing is display.. And I would like to give the possibility to the user to see this in landscape.

The hierarchy is :

```
 • View 
    • ScrollView
       • LineChartView
```

So what constraints should I add to do that ?

[image: initial state]
[image: when the user scroll]

Thank you very much

Comment: Hello. You problem is with the red square right?

Comment: Hello @SilviuSt thank you for your answer. Actually I need to set constraints for the UIView and the UIScrollView. Does constraints affects the contentSize of the UIScrollView ?

Comment: I don't quite understand which is view and which is scrollview, can you tell me? No, constrains does not affects contentSize. Default is the size of uiscrollview

Comment: The green box is UIScrollView and the pink box the UIView. I would like to have the scrollview in full width on to have the possibility to scroll to see the entire UIView (the size of the UIView is updated when the user scrolls to the left to load more data). How should I do ?

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: @SilviuSt It does thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the coments I have elaborated an answer:

**First Step**:

Right click from child ScrollView to parent View

[image]

**Second Step**:

Chose these constrains (You can select multiple at once by holding shift key) then tap on Add Constraints:

[image]

**Third Step**:

Drag with right click from scrollview onto itself and it will pop another message:

[image]

**Forth step**:

Tell him to keep current height( you can add here different constraints but it will do it for now)

[image]

As for the child UIView you can do the same and see after that what happens.

To be able to scroll please note that after you modified the size of  the graph containing UIView you must also set the UIScrollView contentSize to match the graph UIView size.